# Broadcasting pandas dataframe to two dimensional matrix

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of size 12x24 which appears as (I have displayed truncated version):

```
HE   1    2     3    4    5  
0    1  1.8   2.5  3.5  8.5  
1    2  2.6   2.9  4.3  8.7  
2    3  4.4   2.3  5.3  4.3  
3    4  2.6   2.1  4.2  5.3
```

The column names are number 1 through 12 (representing months) and rows are numbered 1 through 24 (representing hours).

I have another `DateTable` dataframe which has data as follows:

```
Date        Month   Hour
2001-01-01  1       1
2001-02-01  2       4
2001-01-05  1       3
2011-01-31  3       2
2012-01-01  1       5
```

I want to broadcast the values from 12x24 array into the `DateTable` to get the following:

```
Date        Month   Hour Values
2001-01-01  1       1    3.5
2001-02-01  2       4    5.3
2001-01-05  1       3    2.5
2011-01-31  3       2    2.6
2012-01-01  1       5    1.8
```

I envision creating some kind of multiindex from the 12x24 table and using against the DateTable but not quite sure about the syntax as I am struggling with syntax.

Comment: You can use pandas `melt` function to create a lookup table from your 12x24 and then join it to the `DateTable`
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html

Comment: Adding 3 lines of incorrect syntax adds value to the post? Feel free to not answer instead of passing around judgement. I already wrote why it didn't work. Have you ever tried implementing multiindexing? If you have then you should know how finicky it is.